# Python Datetime Index and Dict Mapping

Tags: python-2.7, datetime, dataframe

I'm new to datetime and have a problem with what I think should be a simple operation - but I cant figure it out.

I have a dataframe similiar to this:

```
                          EXITS     ENTRIES   DAYOFWEEK     HOUR     HOMEGAME
 DATETIME                   
 2012-08-01 04:00:00     469.000    409.000     2             4         0
 2012-08-01 08:00:00    1127.000    4724.000    2             8         0
 2012-08-01 12:00:00    6675.000    5911.000    2            12         0
 2012-08-01 16:00:00    7575.000    10215.000   2            16         0
 2012-08-01 20:00:00    3430.000    12024.000   2            20         0
 ...
```

I have the following dict:

```
{'08-01-2012': 1,
 '08-03-2012': 1,
 '08-04-2012': 1,
 '08-05-2012': 1,
 '08-13-2012': 1,}
```

The dict indicates the dates on which there were home games.  I want to use a map function (or really any efficient means) to change the value in HOMEGAME in the dataframe to a 1 on dates when there was a home game.  I don't care about the time in the dataframe - if the date in the dataframe index matches a date in the dict I want to change the 0 in the HOMEGAME column in the dataframe to a 1. (So in this example ALL the 0s in HOMEGAME would become 1s because I don't care about the time).

I'm not sure how to do this since the dataframe index contains both a date and time while the dict contains on ly a date.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 2):

To extract a `datetime.date` object from a `datetime.datetime` object, you can use the `date()` method on the datetime.

([Source](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/datetime.html))